# What do the letters 'BLA' refer to in `man nft`?

Tags: nftables

**`man nft`** has this section:

[image]

Do the letters B-L-A stand for something?  *(I've already ruled out **Bla Bla**.)*

---

GNU/Linux Debian Stretch 9.6

Comment: Very likely the result of a formatting error, whatever those letters were meant to represent in the source of the man page. The current [online man page](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html) has expaneded the "(IPV6) EXTENSION HEADER EXPRESSIONS" paragraph with details, and doesn't contain "BLA".

Answer (score 3):

I get the impression it doesn’t mean anything; it’s the resulting of formatting

```
<refsect1>
    <title>bla</title>
    <refsect2>
        <title>IPv6 extension header expressions</title>
        <para>
            IPv6 extension header expressions refer to data from an IPv6 packet's extension headers.
        </para>
    </refsect2>
```

which was introduced [in April 2014](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit?id=0eb9a25) and looks like a placeholder.

The text was removed without comment [in February 2017](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit?id=864a1b44e1937a42753648644a812f70f9500a73).